# How to show the font panel on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I show the Font panel programatically on Mac OS X?

I see that it's part of the default menu that's created but "Show Fonts" is greyed out. The are also no Action for it in the "Connections Inspector".

Answer (score 1):

Found out:

```
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] orderFrontFontPanel:self];
```